# In execv i am sending my mongo dB password as command line but other user are able to see that mongo password in process list(ps uaxww |grep -i mongo)

Tags: c++

```
execv(ssh_command.get_command().c_str(), &args.front());
```

parameters in execv are below.

```
ssh_command.get_command()  - /usr/bin/ssh
args                       - Exporting mongo dB user and password
```

how i can prevent to not show password in process list?

Comment: SSH does not accept a password on the commandline, are you sure that is necessary and that the command is correct? Either way, I think you'll get a better answer on SuperUser. Voting to migrate your question to there.

Comment: I am exporting username and password( export MONGODB_USERNAME=cdis-domain; export MONGODB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXX) through command line

Comment: What does this have to do with your SSH command? Please show the exact command you use.

Comment: There is `execve` where you can add environment variables.

Comment: In execve , password will display in environment.